# Set cookie in angular interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, request, interceptor

I have angular interceptor function. In this function I have request object.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return next.handle(req);
}
```

What I want to do is to set my token in this request cookie with name `my-token`. How can I do that? 
Of course I have access on token inside this function.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add Authorization header to your request:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest < any >, next: HttpHandler) {
    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', this.your_token)
    });

    return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. I have a use case where I need to store the token in a cookie because some requests do not proceed from my angular app (requests that follow from a proxy redirect and originate in a html document asking for its resources.